# How would I make this type of reverb or multi tap echo?

Tags: reverb

I hear this in many songs and I can't think of a better example than this

Its like a cross between a delay and reverb.

What would be the best method or replicating this type of echo. I use Sound Forge so I don't know if the program will have the capability of this type of reverb, please suggest other software that I can use to achieve this effect.

If find more examples I'll post them here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do something like this with something like a tape delay that allows an additional effect send on the pre-feedback delay, or which has an additional reverb on the delay.

Comment: SO basically its a multi layered effect ... interesting ...